# Central Difference Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Solve the following using the central difference method:

$y(x)= y'+ y + 2x$  where $0 < x < 4$  with $n=4$ subintervals (thus $h=1$).

Given that $y(0)=0$ and $y(3)=1$, find $y(1)$.

Really stuck on this question. Feel like there is an error in the question, shouldn't $y(0)$ and $y(2)$ be given to find $y(1)$ using the central difference method?

Comment: Is there a second derivative somewhere? Surround your equation by single or double $ to use LaTeX/MathJaX.

Answer (score 0):

I really think that your equation is
$$
y''=y'+y+2x.
$$

The central difference quotients for stepsize $h$ are
$$
2h·y'(x)\approx y(x+h)-y(x-h)\\
h^2·y''(h)\approx y(x+h)-2y(x)+y(x-h)
$$
With $h=1$ you get
$$
2y(x+1)-4y(x)+2y(x-1)=y(x+1)-y(x-1)+2y(x)+4x\\
\iff y(x+1)-6y(x)+3y(x-1)=4x
$$
Evaluating the boundary conditions, the resulting linear system
\begin{aligned}
y(2)-6y(1)+3·0&=4\\
1-6y(2)+3y(1)&=8
\end{aligned}

can easily be solved for the values of $y(1)$ and $y(2)$.